# Blazor sharing css style sheet and svg across multiple project

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

What is the correct way to share CSS style sheets and vectors across multiple projects?

I have created a CSS style sheet to the `wwwroot/css` and added to my _Host.cshtml like this:

```
<link href="css/mystylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

It works great however, other than copying to each project's `wwwroot/css` I cannot figure what the correct way to share it is.

For my vector's I could create a component for each one but that seems like a lot of extra work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have about 8 different websites and want to share CSS and javascript, create a new web project to host the CSS and javascript and share between all those 8 websites.

An additional benefit of a separate website which hosts the CSS/js will be that you can host on different regions and it will be like your own CDN.

The domain can be something like:

```
https://cdn.mywebsite.com/resources/js/someFile.min.js
https://cdn.mywebsite.com/resources/css/someFile.min.css
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into making a [razor class library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) to share your resources.

Comment: This actually makes way more problems for me.  razor class library is .NET Standard 2.0, the rest of my projects are .NET Core 3.1 and using C# 8.  This is too much of a workload to move backward.